# WordPress functions.php Problem

Tags: php, wordpress, function, blogs

Can a function inside the functions.php file call another function from within functions.php? I'm guessing yes and which is why I wrote the code below, but it doesn't work for some reason. Can anyone please check it out and help me.

I tried calling pageBarColor() from register_sidebar()

Thanks.

```
<?php
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
  register_sidebar(array(
   'before_widget' => '<li class="sidebarModule">',
   'after_widget' => '</li><!-- end module -->',
   'before_title' => '<h2 class="moduleTitle '.pageBarColor().'">',
   'after_title' => '</h2>',
  ));
}

function pageBarColor(){
    if(is_category('3')) {
        return "color1";
    } elseif(is_category('4')) {
        return "color2";
    } elseif(is_category('5')) {
        return "color3";
    } elseif(is_category('6')) {
        return "color4";
    } elseif(is_category('7')) {
        return "color5";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please specify what doesn't work. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No error messages. Just returns nothing, page loads with nothing changed. Actually a space that's because I've given it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that when you call `register_sidebar` Wordpress has not yet executed the code which determines the result of `is_category`. If you try calling your `pageBarColor` function straight after defining it you'll find it doesn't return anything. One way of working around this would be to hook into the `dynamic_sidebar_params` filter (which is called when you call `dynamic_sidebar` in your templates, assuming you do) and update your widget `before_title` values, something like this:

```
function set_widget_title_color($widgets) {
    foreach($widgets as $key => $widget) {
        if (isset($widget["before_title"])) {
            if(is_category('3')) {
                $color = "color1";
            } elseif(is_category('4')) {
                $color = "color2";
            } elseif(is_category('5')) {
                $color = "color3";
            } elseif(is_category('6')) {
                $color = "color4";
            } elseif(is_category('7')) {
                $color = "color5";
            }

            if (isset($color)) $widgets[$key]["before_title"] = str_replace("moduleTitle", "moduleTitle ".$color, $widget["before_title"]);
        }
    }
    return $widgets;
}
add_filter('dynamic_sidebar_params', 'set_widget_title_color');
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, but i know nothing about actions, so could you please link me to a requisite page.

Thanks for the answer..

Comment: I tried this and I am calling dynamic_sidebar in my theme, but nothing changes.

Comment: my bad! I am not calling the dynamic_sidebar in my sidebar.php

instead I have this:

<?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar()) : ?>
<li><!-- stuff shown here in case no widgets active --></li>
<?php endif; ?>

and the rest of my sidebar is manually made.

is there any other way to do the color changes.

Comment: This page of the Wordpress codex explains actions and filters (although the `dynamic_sidebar_params` action is not actually documented): http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

Comment: It's an array, which is passed to the filter function by Wordpress, containing parameters for each widget in a sidebar.

Comment: I have added an example for a static sidebar in my answer to your followup-question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180689/change-widgets-css-class-names-for-different-category-pages-in-wordpress/2190529#2190529